# Uniqueness of rank $r$ and $r+1$ solutions to underdetermined linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Say you have an linear operator $\mathcal{A}: \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ and a vector $\vec b \in \mathbb{R}^p$, with $p < mn$.
Assume that the linear equation 
$$\mathcal{A}(M) = \vec b$$
has at least one solution matrix $M_*$ with rank $r$.

My question is: Is it possible that there is only one unique solution matrix $M_{X}$ with rank $r+1$ ? My intuition screams "NO!", however I can't manage to prove it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the solution set is the affine space 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x & 1 & 1\\
1 & x & 1\\
1 & 1 & x
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then it has rank $1$ for $x=1$, but rank $2$ only for $x=-2$.

Comment: True... Thank you very much. So my intuition was completely wrong here!